# What is a good way to write a javadoc to a method that just redirects to another method?

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

So, I am writing documentation for the code. I have lots of methods that just redirect input to another method, e.g.:

```
  public static ObjectOutputStream openBinOut(String path) throws IOException {
return openBinOut(new File(path));
}
```

Intellij prompts to include `@return` etc., but I don't know if it makes sense. What would I put in this `@return` then?

So far I am writing the javadoc like this, but I have doubts. Should I really include `@return` if the overall description seems sufficient?

```
  /**
   * Redirects to {@link #openBinOut(File path)}, hands on IOException
   * @param path
   * @throws IOException
   */
```

Comment: beware: the doc you are showing is incorrect: in this method the param is of type String while the other method has a param of type File. And that's what you should document :)

Comment: yeah, but that's the point?.. it takes the String path and makes a new File out of it in the method it redirects to. otherwise, any other suggestions? should I include ```@return```?

Comment: @Hulk thank you. Sorry for bothering, but what would be a good doc for ```@return``` if it just redirects to another method?  Should it be something like ```{@link #openBinOut(File path)} return value``` or should I specify the redirected method's return value fully?

Answer (score 1):

As this is a public method, yes you should document parameters, return type and values and exceptions thrown (if any). The fact that this redirects to another method, however, is an implementation detail and should be omitted.

Ideally, users should only need to read the documentation of the method - that is what is displayed to them in most IDEs when deciding which method to use.

Just copy the parts of the JavaDocs that are exactly the same, but be careful to note the differences. Each method documentation should clearly document the purpose of the method and the relevant pre- and post conditions (and that includes parameters and return values and possible exceptions).